# Java memory allocation rules

Tags: java, memory, testng, heap-memory

I came across an issue, but cannot understand the reasons why it happens. I develop automation tests, and now there is a task to compare users' data count in our internal DB and in our vendor's DB.

So we have ~8k users and I need to compare their statements count.

Steps I perform:

1. Get users from DB with their statements count (done once with `HashMap<userId, count>`)
2. Perform API call for each userId, get JSON with list of JSON objects and map them (with Apache HttpClient)
3. Compare count from DB with count of mapped objects.

Problem:
If I perform it with `@Test` using TestNG, after ~2-3k requests, I receive error *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space* on the step of performing API call (`httpClient.execute`).

If I run it as class with same steps in main method, I can perform more than 8k requests without no issues and heap errors.

So the question, is there any memory allocation differences for running tests and for running classes?

```java
public class TransactionsCountTest extends BaseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 int i = 1;
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
        HashMap<String, String> users = databaseHelper.getTransactionUserIdsWithCount();
        TransactionsCountTest transactionsCountTest = new TransactionsCountTest();

        for (String user : users.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(i);
            transactionsCountTest.compareStatementsCount(user, users.get(user));
            i++;
        }
}

private void compareStatementsCount(String user, String DbCount) {

        int dbCount = Integer.parseInt(DbCount);
        int vendorCount = 0;

        try {
            logger.info("Checking " + user);
            List<SalesItemShort> venTransactions = Helpers.getCollectionFromResponse(salesDataSteps.getUserSalesData(user).getBody(), SalesItemShort[].class);
            vendorCount = venTransactions.size();
            assertEquals(vendorCount, dbCount);
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("was NOT")) {
                logger.info("Request timeout for user " + user);
            } else {
                logger.info("Data for user " + user + " is incorrect");
                logger.info("Transactions in DB " + dbCount);
                logger.info("Transactions in Vendor " + vendorCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], also where are you executing your test. Is it in an environment that may have limited memory, etc.?

Comment: i execute it on my laptop, both runs are done in the same environment

Comment: What are you setting your heap to? It might be as simple as having less heap memory one way vs. the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory issue while running tests through testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361177/memory-issue-while-running-tests-through-testng)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question relates to earlier versions of TestNG, where issue has been fixed according to their release notes. Anyways, increasing heap size should help.

Another solution is to work with InputStreams themselves and not convert big responses to String and then to DTOs.
E.g Jackson may map InputStreams to DTOs with his mapper.

Thx all!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you hit an `OutOfMemoryError` exception from within TestNG for a lesser iteration when compared to running the same tests via a `main()` method is because of TestNG.

- TestNG as part of its reporting capabilities wires in a few default listeners out of the box.
- The reporting listeners rely on an object called `ITestResult` to keep track of every test method's result.
- The `ITestResult` object internally remembers every `java.lang.reflect.Method` object for all of the `@Test` methods that were executed.
- So when you run a lot of tests using TestNG, the memory starts bloating because of all these `java.lang.reflect.Method` references that are still stuck in memory and which would get flushed only after the test execution is completed.

You can do the following to basically circumvent some of these and still get away from not having to increase your heap size.

1. Upgrade to the latest released version of TestNG (As of today its 7.4.0)
2. Enable TestNG to run in a memory friendly way by setting the JVM argument `-Dtestng.memory.friendly=true`
3. Disable the default listeners using the parameter `-usedefaultlisteners=false`.

This should start causing TestNG to run in a memory friendly way (This is only to some extent. There's still some work to be done in TestNG to further reduce its memory foot print)

If you are running the test using IntelliJ, then you can uncheck the checkbox "Use default reporters" from your Run configuration

[image]

If you are using the surefire plugin, then you can set the `usedefaultlisteners` to `false` via the properties (As shown below)

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```